# I am trying to use one line of user inputs to populate two different 2d arrays. One being a String and the other an int

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm creating a maze runner project for school.   The user decides the length and width of an array and then inputs danger values into said array. I'm asking for user input in one line; a bunch of integers separated by spaces representing danger values. Then, the user decides where to start, marked with a *. After that an AI decides which coordinate around it has the least "danger" and then moves there, making sure to not move into a coordinate it has already been in.

I'm using a for loop to populate two 2d arrays. One being a `String[][]` and the other an `int[][]`. The reason for this is I'm using the `String[][]` in order to print since I have to change one of the `int`s to a * in order to mark user location. I'm using the `int[][]` to do the math since I can use comparisons (`<`,`>`, etc.) to decide where to move. I can't get the `for` loops to use just the user inputs once. The user would have to input their preferred danger values twice in order for the code to proceed. Any advice?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)    //for loop to repeat question for how ever many rows
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the danger in row " + i + ", seprated by spaces: " );   //what's the danger of this row
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j ++)    //for every row, column space
        {
            mazeMath[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
            mazePrint[i][j]=keyboard.next();
        }
    }
```

For example: If the user decides that there are 7 columns in the array; the user would then have to input their preferred danger values twice, 7 times each. I assume this is to populate both arrays but I don't know how to mediate the problem.

Thanks!

Hunter

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without seeing all of your code, but there may be a very simple way out: you can print `int`s just as easily as `String`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope i got you correctly: at the part of the code u posted, the User only should enter the "danger"-values like: "3 2 4 5", no '*' is entered at this point.

If u want to save the input once in a `String`-array and additionionally to an `int`-Array u can try like this to make it with only one user-input per row:

First read as `String` and then parse this `String` to an `Integer`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)    //for loop to repeat question for how ever many rows
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the danger in row " + i + ", seprated by spaces: ");   //what's the danger of this row
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)    //for every row, column space
        {
            mazePrint[i][j] = keyboard.next();
            mazeMath[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(mazePrint[i][j]);
        }
    }
```